# Aiogram 3 не получается настроить пересылку в другой чат

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Пытаюсь настроить уведомление о выходе из группы в другой чат, но не совсем могу разобраться как настроить эту отправку(

```
@router.chat_member(
    ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(LEAVE_TRANSITION),
    F.chat.type == ChatType.SUPERGROUP
)
async def left_member_alert(event: ChatMemberUpdated) -> Any:

    if chat_member is not None:
        if ChatMemberStatus == "KICKED":
            reason = "Исключен администратором"
        else:
            reason = "Вышел сам"
    else:
        return

    try:
        await message.reply(LOG_CHAT_ID,f'Пользователь вышел', parse_mode="HTML")
        #     LOG_CHAT_ID,
        #     f'Пользователь <a href="tg://user?id={User.id}">{user_full_name}</a> '
        #     f"(@{user_username}) {reason} из чата {chat_title}.\n"
        #     f"Ссылка на чат: NONE",
        #     parse_mode="HTML"
        # )
        # sheet_for_left_members.append_row([str(User.id), user_username, str(chat.id), chat_title, chat_link, reason])
        print("Вышел кто-то")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Ошибка {e}")
```